# How to render key value pairs from object react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

This is object data that I have stored in my this.state.profile from an API request.

What I need to do know is render the values from the keys to the web broswer. I am trying with the code below which does not work. Also how do I render the objects within side this object? This is all so confusing :(

```
{
    "localizedLastName": "King",
    "lastName": {
        "localized": {
            "en_US": "King"
        },
        "preferredLocale": {
            "country": "US",
            "language": "en"
        }
    },
    "firstName": {
        "localized": {
            "en_US": "Benn"
        },
        "preferredLocale": {
            "country": "US",
            "language": "en"
        }
    },
    "profilePicture": {
        "displayImage": "urn:li:digitalmediaAsset:C5603AQGjLGZPOyRBBA"
    },
    "id": "fm0B3D6y3I",
    "localizedFirstName": "Benn"
}
```

How I am trying to render it:

```
const { profile } = this.state;

const profileList = Object.keys(profile).map((key,value)=>{
  return (
      <div>{key}{value.toString()}</div>
  );
})

{ profileList }
```

Comment: `which does not work` only response to that is `you did something wrong`. What does not work? Are you getting errors? If you use map to create a list of jsx objects you should give them a key prop:  `<div key={key}>` or you will get warnings. Could you give us an example of what you want the html to look like based off that data object?

Answer (score 5):

try:

```
return (
   {Object.entries(profile).map(([key,value]) => {
      return (
         <div>{key} : {value.toString()}</div>
      )
   })}
)
```

the iteration needs to happen inside of the `return` with the map returning inside its iteration.

Answer (score 1):

You could build up your object outside your render call like below and just render it (elements).

```
var elements = [];
for (var prop in this.state.profile) {
    elements.push(<div>{prop} : {this.state.profile[prop].toString()}</div>)
}
```

If it's not working my guess would be your state isn't initialised or your target js version doesn't support Object.entries

Comment: There's a problem with this, rendering nested objects. You should do a deep check for this

Comment: Based on the question it doesn't sound like he wants to render child properties separately. If you do you'd just need to put the logic into a function, check if it's an object and recursively call the function.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need to deal with nested objects:

```
{
    ...
    "firstName": {
        "localized": {
            "en_US": "Benn"
        },
        "preferredLocale": {
            "country": "US",
            "language": "en"
        }
    }...
}
```

If you try to render the value on the key `firstName`, you will get a object as value, and React can't render objects as elements.

And if you call `toString()` on it, you will get `[Object object]` as value.

To solve this, you gonna need some recursion:

```
const objToString = obj => {
  let result = []; 

  Object.keys(key => {
    if(typeof obj[key] === 'object'){
      let children = (<div>{key} : {objToString(obj[key])}</div>)
      result.push(children)
    } else
      result.push(<div>{key} : {obj[key]}</div>)
  })
}

...


const profileList = objToString(profile)
```

This should give you this something like:

```
...
<div>firstName: 
  <div>localized:
    <div>en_US: Benn</div>
  </div>
</div>
...
```